# MVC App For SharePoint 2013: Error: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: sharepoint, model-view-controller, unauthorized

I'm creating a MVC App for SharePoint 2013, I'm trying to create an App, I only made the basic project, I have a self-signed certificate, I install it with:

```
$publicCertPath = "C:\Cert\DaviviendaCert.cer"
$certificate = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2($publicCertPath)
New-SPTrustedRootAuthority -Name "DaviviendaCert" -Certificate $certificate
$realm = Get-SPAuthenticationRealm
$specificIssuerId = "925DE7EA-9B68-418C-8DB3-F5598644A6A4"
$fullIssuerIdentifier = $specificIssuerId + "@" + $realm 
New-SPTrustedSecurityTokenIssuer -Name "DaviviendaCert" -Certificate $certificate -RegisteredIssuerName $fullIssuerIdentifier –IsTrustBroker
iisreset 
$serviceConfig = Get-SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig
$serviceConfig.AllowOAuthOverHttp = $true
$serviceConfig.Update()
```

then in the Web.config i have added the IssuerId and the path of the certificate.

When I run the app with F5 in IIS Express it works fine, but when I run the app in Local IIS the browser shows me the message:

The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Source Error:

```
Line 25:                     clientContext.Load(spUser, user => user.Title);
Line 26: 
Line 27:                     clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
Line 28: 
Line 29:                     ViewBag.UserName = spUser.Title;
```

Source File: c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\MVCTest\MvcShp\MvcShpWeb\Controllers\HomeController.cs    Line: 27

Stack Trace:

```
[WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.]
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +8674060
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SPWebRequestExecutor.Execute() +58
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQueryToServer(ChunkStringBuilder sb) +975
   MvcShpWeb.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\MVCTest\MvcShp\MvcShpWeb\Controllers\HomeController.cs:27
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +79
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +242
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +112
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +452
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +452
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +37
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +241
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +111
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +19
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +51
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +111
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
```